# Telethon bot not working - it doesn't receive messages

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

My telethon bot isn't working. It can send messages, but it doesn't receive messages

When I start the bot, it sends `test!` to me. But when I write to it, it doesn't print in the console and doesn't react at all.

code:

```py
api_id = config['BOT_DATA']['api_id']
api_hash = config['BOT_DATA']['api_hash']
bot_token = config['BOT_DATA']['bot_token']
client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)
client.start(bot_token=bot_token)

print('client.get_me().stringify():', client.get_me().stringify())

client.send_message(672188374, 'test!')

@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def newMessageHandler(msg):
    global users

    text = msg.text
    userID = msg.user_id

    if text[0] == '/':
        print(f'New command from {msg.username}!')

        if text == '/start':
            print('Start command')

            if not userID in users:
                await client.send_message(msg.chat_id, 'Hey!\nTo get chatID just resend message from channel/chat to me! But before you need to login')
            else:
                await client.send_message(msg.chat_id, 'Hey!\nTo get chatID just resend message from channel/chat to me!')
    else:
        print(f'New message from {msg.username}!')

    await client.send_message(msg.chat_id, str(msg.stringify()))

    print('\n\n')

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: Please make sure to enable `logging`, as described in https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/updates.html, and report back if there is any error.

Comment: @Lonami Thanks for the answer. It helped. It was a stupid mistake. Please write this as an answer - I will mark it as a solution.